# Maven plugin additional executions

Tags: maven-plugin

I need to execute the same maven plugin more than once in the same phase.

What I want:

1. Execute maven-assembly-plugin
2. Execute myplugin (depends on step 1)
3. Execute maven-assembly-plugin again (depends on step 2)
4. Execute myplugin again (depends on step 3)

Execution order when I define the plugins sequentially (same order as above):

1. Execute maven-assembly-plugin
2. Execute maven-assembly-plugin again
3. Execute myplugin
4. Execute myplugin again

My solution is to combine all executions in my own plugin to control the exact order, but I don't think it's the best way to do it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to run the plugins during the same exact phase? Can't you use some other related phase? Maven has a lot of phases nowadays :) e.g. "prepare-package" vs. "package".  I would probably try to define multiple executions for the plugin like this (bwt this is not a real-world scenario):

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Not sure if it will work for your desired order though. Might be worth a try.

Comment: This is a good solution for my specific problem. I realize that the two first executions should be in the prepare-package phase. But what if I needed more than two executions ? I would prefer not to distort the semantic of phases by using them as a workaround. What I would need then is to easily refine the lifecycle by adding phases (ex: package-step1, package-step2, package-step3, etc.). Maybe maven doesn't support this. I'll take a look at the build lifecycle override. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I suspect the current available phases are pretty much built-in. They've added new phases during the history of the tool for different types of needs but your example is pretty refined :)